# How can I easily unpack extra elements of array into single variable?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a multidimensional array which I am looping through in Python. The second dimension of the array is variably sized like such:

```
data = [
    [1, 2, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 9],
    [1, 3, 4, 2, 1],
    [3, 2, 1, 4]
]
```

When looping through it, is there any easy way to unpack the second-and-on elements?
Ideally I'd want something like this:

```
for base, argtype, *args in data:
    get_func(base, argtype)(*args)
```

This does work, but I'm stuck with something like this:

```
for entry in data:
    base = data[0]
    argtype = data[1]
    args = data[2:]
    get_func(base, argtype)(*args)
```

I just want something that looks much cleaner, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have *is* valid syntax in python3.x:

```
>>> for base, argtype, *args in data:
...     print(base, argtype, args)
... 
1 2 [0, 0]
1 2 [0, 1]
2 1 [9]
1 3 [4, 2, 1]
3 2 [1, 4]
```

---

In python2.x, you're pretty much stuck with what you've got.  There are some variants to make it *shorter*:

```
for entry in data:
    get_func(*entry[:2])(*entry[2:])
```

But I'm not convinced that's better...

You could also create a simple helper generator for example:

```
>>> gen = ((x[0],x[1],x[2:]) for x in data)
>>> for base, argtype, args in gen:
...    print(base, argtype, args)
... 
1 2 [0, 0]
1 2 [0, 1]
2 1 [9]
1 3 [4, 2, 1]
3 2 [1, 4]
```

You could even do something a little clever with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> unpacker = operator.itemgetter(0,1,slice(2,None,None))
>>> for base, argtype, args in map(unpacker, data):
...     print(base, argtype, args)
... 
1 2 [0, 0]
1 2 [0, 1]
2 1 [9]
1 3 [4, 2, 1]
3 2 [1, 4]
```

But again, I'm not really sure if this gains you anything better than what you already have.